# excel 2007 how to automate conditional formatting

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I have lots of cells to assign a formula to for conditional formatting.

I tried to record a macro to automate it but conditional formatting is not recorded. Is it even possible to write some VBA to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
With Range("A1")
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="2", Formula2:="3"
    .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 33
End With
```

i.e. values between 2 and 3 will colour the cell blue.